# Getting Server Error when Posting empty String in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

In the post request I am posting some parameter to the server as a request body . But unable to post empty string . So the question is that can we make post request with empty string if yes then how?
My code snippet is ..

```
HashMap<String, String> paramList = new HashMap<>();
        paramList.put("ApplicationCode", Constant.Application_Code);
        paramList.put("LoginType", Constant.getLoginType(spnLoginType.getSelectedItem().toString()));
        paramList.put("BrandCode", Constant.BRAND);
        paramList.put("CountryCode", Constant.CountryCode);
        paramList.put("CompanyId", etCompanyId.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
        paramList.put("UserId", etUserId.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
        paramList.put("AppVersion", Constant.API_VERSION_VALUE);
        paramList.put("IpAddress", "");
```

> paramList.put("IpAddress", ""); here I am posting empty String that
>   does not work
>
> And if I post like this    paramList.put("IpAddress", "null"); worked
>   fine.

Comment: Just be sure that the Server can handle an incoming json data with a null and treat it as empty.

Comment: @t0mm13b Empty string working fine when I post using Postman

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya what do you mean?

Comment: @Champandorid rectify your server side code

Comment: Is this server api your own code or somebody else? If its your own code running on server side, adjust it.

Comment: @t0mm13b When I send Empty string as JSONObject worked fine . But when send as a String does not worked . I think it's a issue related to volley.

Comment: OP, will have to ask you to stop right there, why are you blaming volley?

Comment: You did not tell why you cannot send "". Which errors do you get? From who? And if indeed you can send an empty string with Postman than i would blame Volley too.

Answer (score 2):

> In the server-side validation, information is being sent to the server
>   and validated using one of server-side languages. If the validation
>   fails, the response is then sent back to the client .

**But when send as a String does not worked**

**Why ?**

Sloppy mistake coming from server side. Rectify your Server-side Validation .

Comment: No server side issue because when I send as JSONObject request worked fine . But does not worked when send as a String .

Comment: volley is not the cause of it, OP. Look at your own code before pointing the issue elsewhere especially when the volley api is well thought out, designed and well tested.

Comment: @t0mm13b sir ,Indeed

Comment: @Champandorid for make sure send `paramList.put("IpAddress", " ");`